Function wrongly returning empty character string if allocated on the heap
The following code is working as expected, unless I'm using -fmax-stack-var-size=0 with gfortran 12.3, 13.3 or 14.2.1. In which case, the function returns an empty string.
program test_clean_str
    implicit none
    character(len=100) :: input_str
    character(len=:), allocatable :: result_str

    input_str = '  Test String  '

    result_str = clean_str(input_str)

    print *, 'Result:-', result_str,"-"

contains

    function clean_str(str_in) result(str_out)
        implicit none
        character(len=*), intent(in) :: str_in
        character(len=:), allocatable :: str_out

        str_out = trim(str_in)
        print*,"-",str_out,"-"

    end function clean_str

end program test_clean_str

This change of behavior does not occur if the function is rewritten as a subroutine or if I'm working with integer arrays instead of character string.
Does this change of behavior is to be expected ?
Edit: remove the mention to ifort and ifx as they are not concerned, and add precision about the concerned version of gfortran

Could you please specify the versions of the compilers you are using, and show the exact command line as well. But I can reproduce what you see (empty string) with gfortran-9, 10, 11, 12 and 14, but not with ifx 2025.0.1 20241113 which prints out the string as I would expect

Okay... apparently I mixed up my tests. sorry for the confusion. You are right, this question does not concern ifx nor ifort... I have updated the post

Yes, it would have been very strange for such a bug to appear at two compilers separately. A normal bug, report at the Bugzilla. If you are unsure how, I could do it, but it is not difficult.

Don't use options that might confuse you?

I'm not, but I'm investigating another issue (segmentation fault when using ifx -O0 and I suspect a stack overflow) and I thought that using another compiler might help me
